# Windows 10 installs incorrect version

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have reinstalled Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit with a Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit CD. After the installation, I realized, that there has been Windows 10 Home edition installed.

Since the installation never asked for a product key, I tried to enter it after the setup, updates and so on...

An error message says, that the key is invalid.

How did I installed a Home version with Pro CD?
If I have the CD, can I upgrade my version to Pro?. (Reinstalling did not work either.)

Comment: "How did I installed a Home version with Pro CD?" - Which edition did your machine come with?  Edit your question to include this vital information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Windows 10 installer from using the preinstalled serial key without disabling UEFI](https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1391868/prevent-windows-10-from-activating-with-win-8-1-embedded-bios-key#comment2099133_1391868)

Comment: Solution to this problem is to simply perform the upgrade to Professional again using the key you originally used. The answer to the linked duplicate provides a method to install Windows 10 Professional, even if your OEM machine came with, Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some installation media that contains multiple versions. Specifically, I have a Windows 10 ISO that has Pro and Home editions and you have to chose during installation what version you use.
[Screenshot of OS version choice. May also be a dropdown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVTkq.png)